# How to fetch data from MS Access (Database) to dataGridView with specific date?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, ms-access, datagridview

I am developing an Attendance Monitoring System and I need the employee form to select data from ms access with a specific date when it runs, I need it to show different data daily. for example 10 persons timed in just lately this day, it will select that but on the next day it will fetch another batch of data

here's my code

```
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                DateTime dateTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;
                string query = "SELECT FROM TimeinTimeout WHERE InDate=" + String.Format("{0:# MM/dd/yy #}", dateTime);

                command.CommandText = query;

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.Update();
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
                connection.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is type of InDate in Database?

Comment: The type is Date/Time in ms access, and it is in short string

Comment: Try passing datetime as a parameter without string.Format

Answer (score 0):

This allows the user to select a date of all the TimeinTimeout data for a specific day

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from TimeinTimeout where date'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "'", constring); ;
        DataTable sd = new DataTable();
        sdf.Fill(sd);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = sd;
    }
```